# How to output separate CSV files per server name

Tags: powershell, export, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, hotfix

I want my PowerShell script to go out to remote servers, gather hotfix data, and export that data to Excel for each server or one Excel sheet per server.

Currently when I run the script it does go out to each server listed in a `.txt` file and gathers the hotfix data. But it exports that data to one Excel file with a name of all the servers. It's a very long name!

Here's the script:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$Server_Name = Get-Content $dir\computers.txt
Get-HotFix -computername $Server_Name | Export-Csv -Path "$dir\$Server_Name HotFixData.csv" -notype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-Content $dir\computers.txt | Foreach-Object {
   Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ | Export-Csv -Path "$dir\$($_)_HotFixData.csv" -notype
}
```

Comment: This only outputs a _HotFixData.csv file that just gets overwritten every time it writes hotfix data for the next server.

Comment: Make sure the computers file content is made of computers name, one name per line

Comment: Yes. The .txt file list the server names one server name per line

Comment: My bad, I used braces instead of parenthesis to enclose the current object. I fixed it, give it a try.

Comment: That is it! Thank you sir! You are a gentlemen and a scholar